# Generic method for querying Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I would like to have generic method for filtering Entity Framework `IQueryable<TItem>` by `IEnumerable<TEnum>`. Its signature should probably look like this:

```
public static IQueryable<TItem> ApplyFilter<TItem, TEnum>(IQueryable<TItem> items, IEnumerable<TEnum> enumValues, Expression<Func<TItem, IEnumerable<TEnum>, bool>> predicate)
{
     return items.Where(??????);
}
```

and I would want to be able to call it for example like this:

```
IQueryable<Request> requests = service.GetAllRequests();
IEnumerable<RequestState> states = new RequestState[] {RequestState.Active, RequestState.Closed};
Expression<Func<Request, IEnumerable<RequestState>, bool>> predicate = (r, s) => s.Contains(r.State);
requests = ApplyFilter(requests, states, predicate);
```

But what should be inside method's body? How can I convert `Expression<Func<TItem, IEnumerable<TEnum>, bool>>` to `Expression<Func<TItem, bool>>` for use as parameter to "Where" method? Will it work with Entity Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was implementing Sharped's answer I found that it is actually possible to do exactly what I want. The point is to use custom class that inherits from ExpressionVisitor. This class will replace every occurrence of `IEnumerable<TEnum>` parameter within expression tree with its actual value. My final code:

```
public static IQueryable<TFilteredItem> ApplyFilter<TFilteredItem, TEnum>(IQueryable<TFilteredItem> items, IEnumerable<TEnum> enumValues, Expression<Func<TFilteredItem, IEnumerable<TEnum>, bool>> predicate)
{
    ParameterExpression itemParam = predicate.Parameters[0];
    ParameterExpression enumsParam = predicate.Parameters[1];
    var em = new ExpressionModifier<IEnumerable<TEnum>>(enumsParam.Name, enumValues);
    Expression predicateBody = em.Modify(predicate.Body);
    return items.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<TFilteredItem, bool>>(predicateBody, new[] { itemParam }));
}

public class ExpressionModifier<T> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly string parameterName;
    private readonly T newValue;
    public Expression Modify(Expression expression)
    {
        return Visit(expression);
    }

    public ExpressionModifier(string parameterName, T newValue)
    {
        this.parameterName = parameterName;
        this.newValue = newValue;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return node.Name == this.parameterName ? Expression.Constant(this.newValue, node.Type) : base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```

And I am using it like:

```
var requests = this.ServiceManager.Messaging.GetRequests();
var states = new[] {RequestState.Active};
requests = ApplyFilter(requests, states, (i, e) => e.Contains(i.State));
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the predicate should be inside your `ApplyFilter` method (respect of concerns).
One possible way to code this would be :

```
public static IQueryable<TItem> ApplyFilter<TItem, TEnum>(IQueryable<TItem> items, 
              IEnumerable<TEnum> enumValues, Expression<Func<TItem,TEnum>> enumField)
{
     return items.Where(i => enumValues.Contains(enumField(i)));
}
```

with a call like this :

```
requests = ApplyFilter(requests, states, r => r.State);
```

Comment: Yes, that is probably the solution I will use. I was just hoping to get something even more general, i.e. not to be restricted to "Contains" method. Thank you for answering.